# Somar valores selecionados de um checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para um salão de beleza, estou utilizando o componente checkbox na tela a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao selecionar um checkbox e depois desselecionar, o programa executa 2 vezes o cálculo. Como resolver esse problema?

Codigo : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não poderia realizar o cálculo depois? Quando a pessoa clica no Registrar?

Comment: Ah, eu pensei, mas ja que sao muitas opcoes,como iria fazer isso ?

Comment: O objeto Serviço, você concatena o nome e o valor dos serviços são iguais ou variam?

Comment: Os valores variam, e eu concateno o  mome do servico para que no banco de dados apareca algo tipo ( Unha mao,Sobrancelha,Hidratacao)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6FnJbdT.png
Algo do tipo (os ultimos registros)

Comment: Vou fazer uma solução e já posto.

Comment: Tranquilo, no aguardo

Comment: Qual a versão do Visual Studio?

Comment: To usando visual c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o `CheckBox`, eu utilizei o `CheckedListBox`. Criei uma classe **Servico** assim consigo atribuir o nome e o valor de cada serviço e também criei um método dentro de servico para me retornar uma lista populada com alguns itens.

```
public class Servico
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; }
    public List<Servico> lista = new List<Servico>();

    public List<Servico> PopularLista()
    {
        lista.Add(new Servico { Nome = "Unha Pé", Valor = 9.50 });
        lista.Add(new Servico { Nome = "Sobrancelha", Valor = 16 });
        lista.Add(new Servico { Nome = "Escovinha", Valor = 198.50 });

        return lista;
    }
}
```

No método `Form1()` eu já atribuo os valores ao `CheckedListBox`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var servicos = new Servico();
    servicos.PopularLista();

    ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DataSource = servicos.lista;
    ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "Nome";
    ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).ValueMember = "Valor";
}
```

E no evento do Botão, usando Linq, eu obtenho os valores e atribuo nas variáveis:

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Servico> servicosSelecionados = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<Servico>().ToList();
    string descricaoServicos = servicosSelecionados.Select(x => x.Nome).Aggregate((atual, proximo) => atual + ", " + proximo);
    double valorServicos = servicosSelecionados.Sum(x => x.Valor);
}
```